# Visual studio start debugging pop up select json schema windows

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, appsettings

All.
When i open appsettings.json then start debug, VS will popup a window to select json schema.
I try to pick one in the drop-down list or set the schema in my appsettings.json like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/appsettings",
  "AppSetting": {...}
}
```

All of them Can't solve it. 
Any idea ?

[image]

---

Thanks for reply,
First of all i'm using console app.
My project is a socket client connect to other server,so i set my server connection in the appsettings.json.
I need to test my code to connect with different servers,so i keep open appsettings.json.
And here's the most troubling part: when i start debug VS popup select json schema window and cover up my app window totally !


After i start VS in safe mode, didn't popup again, but i'm not sure the problem has been resolved.

Comment: What is your main issue? Could you start debugging under that situation? You can start debugging successfully but it always pop such window to let you choose the schema? And make you confused?

Comment: Does a new created project have the same issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, i edit my question.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT new project not pop up, but I'm not the only one with this problem.

Comment: that means this project used some tools from some vs installed extensions or packages. So you have to check if you install some inherited, third party extensions or packages. If so, please disable them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So strange and we did not face such issue before. Try something like these:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**--> **Manage Extensions**-->**Installed** to check if there is an extension caused that.

**2)** try to reset vs settings under **Tools**->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset vs settings**, and you can also make a backup of your settings.

**3)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then restart VS to test again.

**4)** use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) under **Developer Command Prompt for VS** to start a pure VS to test it.

**5)** create a new project to test whether the issue happens again.

**6)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it if there is a new release version.

**Besides**, if those do not help,  you should describe your issue in detail to share a small sample with us to help us troubleshoot it.